# Hot Restart Configuration failure in MAUI: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsfot.IdentityModel.Abstractions'

Tags: maui, iso

I'm trying to run my MAUI app on an iOS physical device but i keep getting the error message related to  file or assembly 'Microsfot.IdentityModel.Abstractions'. Below is the full message:

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this? It happened after updating my Visual Studio to 17.6.0 Preview 2.

Comment: Did you use the Preview version of Visual Studio before the upgrade?

Comment: Before the upgrade, it was working fine.

Comment: Try cleaning Nugets repository from Visual Studio -> Options -> NuGet Package manager -> Clear all Nuget storage. Close VS, delete all .vs/bin/obj folders. Open VS again and rebuild (This will take time, as all nugets will download again).

Comment: Did not work unfortunately.

Comment: I tried on the official VS version and it worked, seems the problem is with the preview version.